# How can I set items programmatically in kendo ui radiogroup?

Tags: kendo-ui, radio-group

I want to customize the data to be selected in kendo UI radiogroup after loading the widget.

Here is an example with several attempts to accomplish items after initializing kendo UI radiogroup.

https://dojo.telerik.com/oJOZezuQ/2

value can be set after without problems, but items cannot.

Is there a better variant than to regenerate the whole widget when changing items?

Comment: What do you mean by "Items cannot be set"? Your example you are adding items and there value correctly

Comment: I mean, yo can set radioGroup.value("two"); but radioGroup.items([ "one", "two", "three" ]); is not setting.

Comment: I don't see any other way but to recreate the whole widget. Destroy the widget properly before recreating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now implemented it as follows:

https://dojo.telerik.com/oJOZezuQ/9

It seems to me to be a good solution, as the options are not changed during a refresh.

```
<ul id="radiogroup"></ul>
<script>

 var tmpSetOptions = {
  items: [ "one", "two" ],
  value: "one",
  labelPosition: "before",
  layout: "horizontal"
 };

 $("#radiogroup").kendoRadioGroup(tmpSetOptions);

 setTimeout(function(){
  tmpSetOptions.items = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
  $("#radiogroup").kendoRadioGroup(tmpSetOptions);
 }, 5000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to make this work is to remove the kendo widget and then recreate it with the new item:

```html
<div id="radioGroupSection"></div>

<script>
    rg = $("#radioGroupSection");
    rg.html('<ul id="radiogroup"></ul>')
    
    $("#radiogroup").kendoRadioGroup({
      items: [ "one", "two" ],
      value: "one"
    });
    
    setTimeout(function () {
      rg.html('<ul id="radiogroup"></ul>')
    
      $("#radiogroup").kendoRadioGroup({
        items: [ "one", "two", "three" ],
        value: "three"
      });
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

Here is the [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/oJOZezuQ/8)

Comment: i think also there is only this way... Thanks for answer

Comment: @Severin You're welcome! If you think this answered your question, please consider marking it as the answer.